# mysql adaptation of query to show all records of my table

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner in mysql and I have this query :

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN('45' * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS('45' * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(('-75' - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `account` HAVING `distance`<='100' ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

This works well, but it only gives me the distance as results... I want to have all my fields of my table... I tried

Select * from account Where (... ) as distance.. .but it's not working... can anyone help me modify this query... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL, if you want to use an `*` in your `SELECT` statement, in conjunction with other fields/expressions (in other words anything more than just `SELECT *`) you need to use a table alias.  So your code would need to look like this:

```
SELECT a.*,
       ((ACOS(SIN('45' * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS('45' * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(('-75' - longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`

FROM `account` AS a

HAVING `distance`<='100' 

ORDER BY `distance` ASC;
```